# Getting a value to return once string is found

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, printing

I need to have the @r return a value of one if the ISBN is found in the table.

homework problem: Create a procedure called FindABookbyISBN. It accepts one argument @value of type varchar(20) which is the ISBN that someone is looking for. If the procedure finds the book, it displays the book information and returns 1. If it does not find the book, the procedure prints something like “Cannot find book” and returns 0.

The message should look like this:

Found book with isbn 9780393248968

```
1
```

Cannot find book with isbn 9780393248968

```
0


IF OBJECT_ID ('FindABookbyISBN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE FindABookbyISBN

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE FindABookbyISBN @ISBN varchar(20) AS

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BookInfo WHERE ISBN = @ISBN)
    BEGIN 
    PRINT 'Found book with ISBN ' + @ISBN

END

ELSE

BEGIN
    PRINT 'Cannot find book with ISBN ' + @ISBN

END

GO

--testing procedure

--success

Declare @r int

EXEC @r = FindABookByISBN '9780393248968'

Print @r

--failure

Declare @t int

EXEC @t = FindABookByISBN '1234' 

Print @t
```

Comment: Your stored procedure is not returning a status value.

Comment: OH! Thanks so much. I knew it was something simple. Appreciate your input!

Answer (score 2):

Gordon Linoff answered my question in the comment section.

I simply had to add a Return value for it.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BookInfo WHERE ISBN = @ISBN)
    BEGIN 
    PRINT 'Found book with ISBN ' + @ISBN
    Return 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    PRINT 'Book was not found with ISBN ' + @ISBN
    END

GO
```

Comment: Your homework problem is not very good. The de-facto pattern is to return zero for success and non-zero for error/warning. The 1 value should be returned for the not-found condition.

Comment: I am glad you brought this up. This was confusing me. So my teacher provided what the message should look like in the end and it just as you said. Her example: "Found book with ISBN 9780393248968... 0" 'Cannot find book with ISBN 1234... 1". But how the problem is worded it seems like she's looking for the opposite here. I thought she may have made a mistake. What is a de-facto pattern?

Comment: disregard the de-facto question. Do you think I have this mixed up though? Appreciate your help!

Comment: I can't say if you've mixed up your assignment or not without seeing the actual question :-) If the question is the same as listed, then she has it backwards. I'm only suggesting the pattern to follow in the real word, which may differ from academia. That would be a good topic to discuss in class.

Comment: Yeah, I will be bringing it up on Monday for sure. Thanks again for your input.